# Utilizing JNI library: Finding classes

Tags: java, opencv, java-native-interface, javacv

I'm trying to use OpenCv in an Eclipse Java project (via javaCv) and I'm getting run-time `java.lang.ClassNotFoundExpection` and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` errors. The imports look OK and everything runs fine until execution gets to this line:

```
IplImage img = cvLoadImage(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

The class loader seems unable to find `com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer`.

Here's what I've tried:

- I've copied three jar files to `[project_root]\lib`: javacv-windows-x86.jar, javacv.jar and opencv-2.4.4-windows-x86.jar.
- I added all three jars to my build path using Eclipse gui.
- I added `[...]\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin` to my system path.
- I added the following argument to my Eclipse run configuration: `-Djava.library.path=[...]\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin\*`

EDIT:
I was just missing the javacpp jar. I had downloaded javacv-0.4-cppjars from the javacv project and I imported the relevant jar therein (opencv-2.4.4-windows-x86.jar) but I needed to grab [javacpp.jar from a separate google code project](https://code.google.com/p/javacpp/).